# How Can I Set Day Of DateTime in Vb?

Tags: vb.net

I have a DateTime variable like that:

```
Dim tarih2 As New DateTime( _
    year(tarih3), _
    month(tarih3), _
    DateTime.DaysInMonth(year(tarih3), month(tarih3)))
```

and I need to set the day part to a specific value. How can I set day of a DateTime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime` is immutable, so you can't change the value; you can only construct a new instance by either calling `AddDays()` for a relative offset, or by using the constructor in a similar manner to that in your question:

```
tarih2 = new DateTime(year(tarih2), month(tarih2), newDayValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime.AddDays Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx)

`tarih2.AddDays(1) ' adds one day to an instance of DateTime tarih2`

Comment: i know that but i don't need to add days. I need to set some specific value.

Comment: i need to set specific value.